# python download images are not saved to the correct directory

Tags: python, file

When i use python 2.7 to download images from a website, the code as follows:

```
pic = requests.get(src[0])
f = open("pic\\"+str(i) + '.jpg', "wb")
f.write(pic.content)
f.close()
i += 1
```

I want to save the picture into pic directory, but I find that images is saved in the same directory with the name like `pic\1.jpg`. Is this a bug?

In Windows, it's right, but on Ubuntu, it's an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows uses backslashes for file paths](http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/), but Ubuntu uses forward slashes. This is why your save path with a backslash doesn't work on Ubuntu.

You probably want to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to make your path OS agnostic:

```
import os
path = os.path.join('pic', '{}.jpg'.format(str(i)))
f = open(path, 'wb)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
f = open(os.sep.join(['pic', str(i), '.jpg']), 'wb')
```

Now the line should be os agnostic

Comment: Rather use os.path.join